# What is known about this twin prime-power counting function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

This question is motivated by the MathOverflow question [List of properties of Twin primes Dirichlet series](https://mathoverflow.net/q/345133)
 and assumes the following definition of the twin prime-power counting function $k_2(x)$ where $\nu (n)$ is the number of distinct primes in the factorization of $n$.

**(1)** $\quad k_2(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\begin{array}{cc}\{&\begin{array}{cc}1&\nu(n)=1\land\nu(n+2)=1\\0&\text{True}\\ \end{array}\\ \end{array}$

---

The following figure illustrates a discrete plot of the twin prime-power counting function $k_2(x)$ defined in formula (1) above at integer values of $x$ in blue and the standard twin-prime counting function $\pi_2(x)$ in orange.

---

[image: Figure (1)**: Illustration of k_2(x) defined in formula (1) (blue) and pi_2(x) (orange)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $k_2(x)$ defined in formula (1) (blue) and $\pi_2(x)$ (orange)

---

**Question (1)**: Does the twin prime-power counting function $k_2(x)$ defined in formula (1) above take an infinite number of steps?

**Question (2)**: What else is known about the twin prime-power counting function $k_2(x)$ (e.g. asymptotic and error bound)?

**Question (3)**: Is there a reference that provides more information on the twin prime-power counting function $k_2(x)$?

---

The following two figures illustrate discrete plots of $k_2(x)$ in blue, $\pi_2(x)$ in orange. and $2\,\pi_2(x)$ in green. I've validated that $k_2(x)\le 2\,\pi_2(x)$ for $101\le x\le 10,000,000$ and I'm wondering if this relationship continues to hold for all $x\ge 101$.

---

[image: Figure (2): Illustration of k_2(x) (blue), pi_2(x) (orange), and 2 pi_2(x) (green)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of $k_2(x)$ (blue), $\pi_2(x)$ (orange), and $2\,\pi_2(x)$ (green)

---

[image: Figure (3): Illustration of k_2(x) (blue), pi_2(x) (orange), and 2 pi_2(x) (green)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of $k_2(x)$ (blue), $\pi_2(x)$ (orange), and $2\,\pi_2(x)$ (green)

---

Note  in the previous two figures $k_2(x)$ seems to evaluate fairly close to $\pi_2(x)$. The following figure illustrates a discrete plot of $k_2(x)-\pi_2(x)$.

---

[image: Figure (4): Illustration of k_2(x)-pi_2(x)]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of $k_2(x)-\pi_2(x)$